# How to Count Users with a Firebase Cloud Function (getting Function Returned Undefined error)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that assigns a number to a user on `onWrite`. The following code works but something is wrong because the console logs state `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`.

I'm also not sure how to refer to the root from inside the `onWrite` so I've created several "parent" entries that refer to each other. I'm sure there is a better way.

onWrite triggers on this:

```
/users/{uid}/username
```

The trigger counts the children in /usernumbers and then writes an entry here with the uid and the child count + 1:

```
/usernumbers/uoNEKjUDikJlkpLm6n0IPm7x8Zf1 : 5
```

Cloud Function:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.setCount = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/username').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid;
    const parent1 = change.after.ref.parent; //uid
    const parent2 = parent1.ref.parent;      //users
    const parent3usernumbers = parent2.ref.parent.child('/usernumbers/');
    const parent3usernumbersuid = parent2.ref.parent.child('/usernumbers/'+uid);

    parent3usernumbers.once("value")
       .then(function(snapshot) {
       var a = snapshot.numChildren();
       return parent3usernumbersuid.transaction((current) => {
          return (a + 1);
       }).then(() => {
          return console.log('User Number Written', uid, a);
       });
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? How can I get the Function Returned Undefined error to go away?

I should also mention it takes a few seconds for the 'usernumber' entry to be written. I'm guessing it's waiting for the function to return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function have to return a Promise :

```
exports.setCount = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/username').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid;
    const parent1 = change.after.ref.parent; //uid
    const parent2 = parent1.ref.parent;      //users
    const parent3usernumbers = parent2.ref.parent.child('/usernumbers/');
    const parent3usernumbersuid = parent2.ref.parent.child('/usernumbers/'+uid);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parent3usernumbers.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
           var a = snapshot.numChildren();
           return parent3usernumbersuid.transaction((current) => {
               return (a + 1);
            }).then(() => {
               console.log('User Number Written', uid, a);
               resolve({uid : uid, a : a})
            }).catch(function(e) {
               reject(e)
            })
        });
    });
});
```